# jQuery Cycle Plugin - stop at last slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I am using jquery cycle plugin to display a basic slider. I have 5 images.

Code is :

```
$(function(){
  $('#slider').cycle();
});
```

But I want to show the 5 images and at the end of it, stop the animation and keep the last image displayed in it.

I mean, it should not repeat showing the sliders again. Should stop after the slides are shown once.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cycle plugin takes `autostop` as an option parameter...
Just pass in the specified parameter....assuming 5 is the amount of slides you wanna stop at...

```
$(function(){
$('#slider').cycle({autostop:5});
 });
```

Plugins usually allow various options, and its good to refer to the documentation when trying to modify settings.

You can see a list of all available options for this Cycle plugin here...

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html

Comment: thanku. i already tried it before asking. but issue was, i was using "a" tags to cover images. And it was giving a blank slider in between and at the end it was showing this blank slider. I thought it was not working! Removed anchor elements and it works.

Comment: my slideshow is dynamic - ie, the number of slides is unknown. how can it work in this case?  thanks